# Complicated Integral from an Integral Test

Tags: calculus

I have this infinite series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2 +2^{-n}}$$
I can only use Integral, Bounded-Sum, Comparison, and Divergence tests. Divergence Test is inconclusive on this. Integral Test seems promising since the series satisfies the conditions, but $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{x}}{x^2 +2^{-x}} $$
appears to be a difficult integral. Even if I resort to Comparison Test,
$$\frac{n\sqrt{n}-2^{-n}}{n^2}<\frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2 +2^{-n}}$$
It's easy to show $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$ is divergent, but $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-n}}{n^2}$ is (absolutely) convergent with ratio and root test, which I cannot use yet. Thus by Comparison Test, I know that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2 +2^{-n}}$ is divergent. The problem is I can only use the tests I mentioned above, or no tests beyond Comparison Test. So I'm thinking that I just need to evaluate the improper integral for the Integral Test to justify divergence. Any insights on how I should solve the integral or frame my answer in a different way?

Comment: In order to apply the comparison tests it is highly advisable to develop some mathematical intuition...or "educated mathematically guess": your series' sequence has $\;n\sqrt n=n^{3/2}\;$  in the numerator while *the dominant term* in the denominator is $\;n^2\;$ ( since $\;2^{-n}\to0\;$ ) . Thus, *we suspect* our series behaves as the series of $\;\frac{n^{3/2}}{n^2}=\frac1{\sqrt n}\;$ , which diverges....and thus we try to prove somehow (read the answers) that our sequence is bigger than something we know diverges...or the limit comparison test with the series of $\;\frac1{\sqrt n}\;$...

Comment: @DonAntonio True. I knew I needed to find some sequence that is "smaller" and simpler than the original sequence in question so that I can use comparison test (I already suspected it will diverge). What stirred me on that direction is when I tried to find a bigger sequence and found divergence of it (which is inconclusive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2 +2^{-n}}>\frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2 +1}\geq  \frac{n\sqrt{n}}{2n^2}$ and $\sum \frac 1 {2n^{1/2}}$ is divergent.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n\sqrt n}{n^2+2^{-n}}}{\frac1{\sqrt n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+2^{-n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+n^{-2}2^{-n}}=1.$$Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$ diverges, so does your series.